# Try/catch, don't know how to loop this

Tags: exception, try-catch

Here is my main method

```
public static void main (String[] args) {
    Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
    Intro();
    try {
        userInput(console);
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Not a number; try again.");
    }
}
```

I would like the userInput(console); to run again even if the Exception was found. The method userInput(console); runs a program that asks for the radius of a circle and calculates its diameter, circumference, and area. I tried using a while loop outside of the try/catch statement but I don't know what I should use as conditions. Comment if you would like to see the userInput(console) method and I will post that as well.

Comment: Just wrap it into loop use just "true" as condition and "break" to break the loop when you need it.

Comment: Except in my userInput method I only want it to break if the user inputs 0. And when I tried that and entered a string to get the exception I got an infinite loop.

Comment: This *looks* like Java, but please, don't make us guess. Please add a language tag.

Comment: Then you want to add something like if(input == 0) {break;} remember that you need to compare same types and use .equals method instead of == if you compare referenced types (String for example)

Answer (score 1):

Using a `while` loop with a *condition* is ok. Just remember that the condition serves as a flag to define if the iteration should *carry on or stop*, in particular because a *certain condition was met*. In this case, your condition is defined by the user's input validation result. Assuming you used a while like this:

```
while(someCondition) {
    try {
        userInput(console);
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        System.out.println("Not a number; try again.");
    }
}
```

Your `someCondition` variable should be a `boolean` initialized in `true` that is set to `false` when the input is valid or, in your case, when no exception is thrown. You can also set it to `false` after a certain amount if iterations. If you set `someCondition` to false, the next time the while evaluates `someCondition` it is `false`, and the iteration ends.

Another approach is to use a `while(true)` loop and end the iteration by using a `break` statement. It achieves the same in this case, but they're essentially different:

- The `someCondition` approach doesn't cut the current iteration, it lets it finish the processing (considering you have something in the loop that must be done with the valid input, for example).
- By using a `break` statement, that iteration is interrupted and the `while` loop ends without executing the rest of the code encased inside of it.